# reCaptcha pushing down CSS elements

Tags: css, wordpress, recaptcha, contact-form-7

My page is http://bonemarrow.ipage.com/contact/.

I'm using reCaptcha with Contact Form 7 under a Wordpress install. Without reCaptcha, my form looks fine and doesn't interfere with the look of the page. As soon as I pop in the reCaptcha, I new have a gap under the main content area, between it and my footer.

It seems like reCaptcha is pushing the footer div down by about the same height as the reCaptcha table itself. I tried wrapping it in a div of my own (#my_captcha) and setting a height, but that didn't work either.

I also thought it might be because of the way I style the labels and/or fields in my form, so I removed all the styling to see what would happen. No deal, even without styling reCaptcha still insists on introducing that gap.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
footer{
margin-top: -30px;
}
```

This is one way you could do it.

EDIT: Based on your comment...

Well you could just be more specific with your CSS for example like this

```
.some_specific_container footer{
margin-top: -30px
}
```

Assuming that form class only appears on the page I don't see a problem with that.

EDIT 2:

Just took another look, the problem is caused by the iframe, you currently have `visibility:hidden` if you add `display:none` you will fix it. No hacks required. The reason that is happening is because `visibility:hidden` hides an element, but it will still take up the same space as before. The element will be hidden, but still affect the layout. `display:none` hides an element, and it will not take up any space. The element will be hidden, and the page will be displayed as if the element is not there. [source.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Comment: True, I thought about that, but I was trying to avoid a custom style just for this page. Plus I would feel better if I knew what was causing it, rather than just hacking the CSS to make it look right on this page.

Comment: Sorry you edited your comment while I was editing the answer, I agree its always good to get to the root of a problem, but hacks are ok sometimes too ;-)

Comment: In response to your edit: the footer isn't contained within the form class, it would have to be page-specific. And that's fine, and I might even have to do that if I can't figure out why it's happening, but I'd like to learn why it's happening so that I can avoid the same mistake (assuming it's a mistake in my code) in the future.

Comment: Yes you are right about the footer I will remove that from the answer I should have looked properly was not concentrating, we got there in the end I think!

Comment: I'm having a hard time targeting the iframe. It's weird, `div#my_captcha iframe {
 display: none;
}` won't work, but `iframe {
 display: none;
}` does. However, I think I might run into problems if I use the latter. While I can make the one iframe I know I use (subscribe form in footer) visible by targeting it directly, what about other plugins that might use iframes to do something?

Comment: Would be nice if the folks who wrote the reCaptcha plugin had given that iframe an ID. :-)

Comment: By the way, I don't have `visibility:hidden`…I don't have any CSS at all (that I wrote, anyway) targeting iframes.

Comment: The styles are inline, they will not be in the CSS, they are (I'm guessing) added using `style="visibility:hidden;"` in the HTML by a plugin or something. You can't target the iframe as above because its not within a div try `.page-id-391 iframe{ display:none }` thats the class of your body so should be at least specific to that page.

Comment: check the docs for the plugin may let you add an id, even try search through the code for visibility and add the style along with that, could be an option?

Comment: I ended up using the page ID as you suggested, thanks for all your help. I've marked your response as the answer to this question. :)